# How to exit a program at particuliar time while main loop is listening for message?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, exit, tibco

In the main program main loop, I'm listening on a EMS topic by calling tibemsMsgConsumer_Receive. Meanwhile, I want to exit the program at specific time, say 5PM. How can I implement this?

I tried to use the following code but it doesn't work properly in the case there is no message received.

Is there a way I can exit the program when 'while' loop is stuck there?

```
while (1)
{
status = tibemsMsgConsumer_Receive(m_CmbsSpreadMatrixSubscriber, &msg);

  if (status == TIBEMS_OK)
  {
    DoSomething();
  }

  if (getRunTime("hour").c_str()) >= 18)
  {
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Have another thread that sends a message at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [tibemsMsgConsumer_ReceiveTimeout()](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.0.1_january_2011/html/tib_ems_c_and_cobol_ref/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=tib_ems_c_and_cobol_ref.4.35.htm&single=true) and set an appropriate timeout to check your exit condition repeatedly.

From the description on that page:

*This function consumes the next message from the consumer’s destination. When the destination does not have any messages ready, this function blocks:*

- If a message arrives at the destination, this call immediately consumes that message and returns.
- If the (non-zero) timeout elapses before a message arrives, this call returns TIBEMS_TIMEOUT.
- If another thread closes the consumer, this call returns TIBEMS_INTR.

Comment: Thank you, JensG. This is great. Since my backend process starts at 8AM and is needed to exit at 5PM, so I can set Timeout as 9hours. If no msg received, the blocking function will return TIBEMS_TIMEOUT and main program will exit.

Comment: One other question is, I tried to create a separate thread to count the time elapses before the main loop, and when time is 5PM, then call exit in that thread. It seems working well and the main thread does exit too.  Is this a right and safe solution also?

Comment: I can't see your code from here. But `and the main thread does exit too` sounds strange. Are they coupled in any way?

Comment: Before starting the main loop listening on message, I start a thread, and in the thread function I simply count time and exit the program when it's 6PM.

Comment: You will need only one thread to take care of the time to exit, so choose one. But it is recommended to perform adequate cleanup for *all* threads, that part is typically the more complicated thing. Next, when you know that 5pm is 8 hours away, you probably don't need to poll every minute, unless the clock of your machine is unexpectedly changing :-) same principle as above.

Answer (score 0):

before starting the main loop listening on message, I start a thread.

```
boost::thread aThread(&threadFunc);
```

and in the thread function I simply count time and exit the program. Not sure if 
it's safe and right or not...

```
void threadFunc()
{   
    while (true)
    {
        wait(60);

        if (atoi(getRunTime("hour").c_str()) >= 18)
        {
            Log("Now it's 6PM, let's stop and get back tomorrow.");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I recommend to edit that into your question above instead posting it as an answer?